# Yii: CMemCache requires PHP memcache extension to be loaded despite having memcache/memcached installed

Tags: php, nginx, yii, yii1.x

I installed memcached already by running `sudo apt-get install php-memcached` and by running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, here is the result:

[image]

But I still have this error on my Yii project:

[image]

I'm running it in an nginx server.

Comment: do mark the answer if it worked for you as it helps others having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memcache` and `memcached` are two separate extensions. You need to set [`useMemcached`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache#useMemcached-detail) to `true` in order to use `memcached`:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'CMemCache',
    'useMemcached' => true,
],
```

or install `memcache` extension:

```
sudo apt install php-memcache
```